# Sorting array code in VBA (Excel) not working correctly

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote the following code which creates a 3 by 3 table and then sorts the columns from smallest to biggest depending on the values in row 1 (second row). For some reason, with the values below I get to a point where the code does "If( 2>1) Then" but the code then says its FALSE and skips, I have no idea why. Can anyone see what the issue may be?

```
Sub SortButton()

Dim MyArray As Variant
ReDim MyArray(0 To 2, 0 To 2) As Variant
Dim x As Integer, y As Integer, z As Integer
Dim str0 As String, str1 As String, str2 As String

MyArray(0, 0) = MC
MyArray(0, 1) = Branch1
MyArray(0, 2) = Branch2
MyArray(1, 0) = 1
MyArray(1, 1) = 2
MyArray(1, 2) = 0

For x = LBound(MyArray, 2) To UBound(MyArray, 2) - 1
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A9") = x
    For y = (x + 1) To UBound(MyArray, 2)
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A9") = x
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A10") = y
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A11") = MyArray(1, x)
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C11") = MyArray(1, y)
        
        If MyArray(1, x) > MyArray(1, y) Then
            str0 = MyArray(0, x)
            str1 = MyArray(1, x)
                
            MyArray(0, x) = MyArray(0, y)
            MyArray(1, x) = MyArray(1, y)
                
            MyArray(0, y) = str0
            MyArray(1, y) = str1
                
            str0 = ""
            str1 = ""

        End If       
    Next y
Next x

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = MyArray(0, 0)
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1") = MyArray(0, 1)
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1") = MyArray(0, 2)
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2") = MyArray(1, 0)
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2") = MyArray(1, 1)
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2") = MyArray(1, 2)

End Sub
```

First it does 1>2 which returns false, then 1>0 which return true and swaps the columns over, then it does 2>1 but returns FALSE, I can not find out why.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the 1 is being stored as a String after you go through the loop the first time

Comment: change str1 to an integer and remove str1 = "" then I think the code works fine

Comment: @user1236777 Aaaah! completely missed that. Thanks! That made it work.

Comment: btw i think you're printing stuff out to the worksheet to review whats going on.  if you put Stop in your code it will stop at that line, if the then have the locals window open [view -> locals window] then you can see whats going on in detail our hover over things to get there value, hope it helps

Comment: Another option is to use `Debug.Print` which will print values to the Immediate window